# gridview wpf binding anhother gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

**GridView CurrentGrid =Grd_UserList;**

**Grd_UserList.Columns.Clear();**

ı have got this example, ı use "Columns.Clear();" fonc. with Grd_UserList for all item clear but this func. CurrentGrid  cleans all the items

***help me pls***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific in your question , i think you should create a new instance of GridView before affecting the value of Grd_UserList to it